# view pdf from web address without download via flutter_full_pdf_viewer

Tags: flutter

Is it possible to view via flutter_full_pdf_viewer a pdf doc without download it?

The main reason why I do not want to download it is due to copyright reasons, in this case, it will be very easy to share the pdf file (copyright violation)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use google drive to view a pdf using only it's URL so you can either open it in the browser or inside a web view

using [webview_flutter](https://pub.dev/packages/webview_flutter)

```
WebView(
  initialUrl: ('https://docs.google.com/gview?embedded=true&url=${yourPdfPath}'),
  javascriptMode: JavascriptMode.unrestricted,
)
```