# Unhandled Exception: RangeError (index): Invalid value: Valid value range is empty: 0 - For Google Drive PDF

Tags: android, flutter, flutter-dependencies, pdf-viewer

I am using **PDF VIEWER** and fetching **Google Drive Pdf** but it is showing Ranger Error. It was working fine earlier but all of a sudden it is giving me this error of Range Error. I tried different URL and it is working but using google drive pdf it is not working. Earlier it used to work as other links.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:advance_pdf_viewer2/advance_pdf_viewer.dart';

class FmtCH11 extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _GeneralState createState() => _GeneralState();
}

class _GeneralState extends State<FmtCH11> {
  bool _isLoading = true;

  late PDFDocument _doc;

  String url =
      "https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=1oqzz9m6IcJFpXuMWWnvkXYfXPlpfEOBo";

  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    _initPdf();
  }

  _initPdf() async {
    setState(() {
      _isLoading = true;
    });
    final doc = await PDFDocument.fromURL(url);
    setState(() {
      _doc = doc;
      _isLoading = false;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text("Introduction"),
        ),
        body: _isLoading
            ? Center(
                child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
              )
            : PDFViewer(
                document: _doc,
              ));
  }
}
```

**It is showing error -**

```
[VERBOSE-2:dart_vm_initializer.cc(41)] Unhandled Exception: RangeError (index): Invalid value: Valid value range is empty: 0
#0      _Array.[] (dart:core-patch/array.dart:10:36)
#1      _PDFViewerState._loadPage
viewer.dart:149
#2      _PDFViewerState.didChangeDependencies
viewer.dart:125
#3      StatefulElement._firstBuild
framework.dart:5237
#4      ComponentElement.mount
framework.dart:5062
#5      Element.inflateWidget
framework.dart:3971
#6      Element.updateChild
framework.dart:3702
#7      ComponentElement.performRebuild
framework.dart:5111
#8      Element.rebuild
framework.dart:4805
#9      StatelessElement.update
framework.dart:5162
#10     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framew<…>
```

Really Grateful if you help, a little **URGERNT**

Answer (score 0):

your FmtCH11 does not give index error it comes from somewhere else

You can not directly view google drive pdf link these are 2 options :

Show it in web view
https://stackoverflow.com/a/60599478/6656661

or

Download in document directory of application then show

https://www.syncfusion.com/forums/176887/how-to-load-pdfs-host-with-google-drive-or-dropbox